# Does Node JS Express module handle Requests Asynchronously?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, express, asynchronous

I'm new to NodeJs and Express server.
I have a simple app that handle requests :

```
app.post('/addToken',   tokens.addToken);
app.post('/sendNoti',   iosNotification.sendNotification);`
app.get('/allNames',    names.babyNames);`

var server = app.listen(8081, function () {

    var host = server.address().address
    var port = server.address().port

    console.log("server listening at http://%s:%s", host, port)
})
```

If I will create 3 http request in the client, and execute them one after the other does this module will execute then in parallel or one after the other?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it does, if you create them in a list of promises. it allows you to start all the http request at the same time, and then wait for their answers. Like you would do for threads.

see this tutorial on how to set them up

https://strongloop.com/strongblog/promises-in-node-js-with-q-an-alternative-to-callbacks/

Comment: I want the client side to be independet in the request creation and not to confirm him to a specific type of creation. Is there any way to ensure the asynch in the server side?

Comment: I would say that by default, it is not asynchronous on the server side, you have to make it so. By doing it yourself, or by using npm library like https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-promise

Answer (score 0):

No, Express does not handle request asynchronously. The 3 http request you create will be executed one after the other, cause there's only one main thread.

> **Only the I/O operations occur asynchronously.**